# How do I store and transport microcontroller boards safely?

Tags: microcontroller, esd, static

I'm looking for a carrying case for my various electronics components, mostly various microcontroller boards (Arduino, Teensy, etc). I've seen a lot of people use plastic tool boxes, sometimes with foam inserts. Do these present a problem with ESD? Is there a particular type of plastic I should look for that has lower static buildup?

Comment: Yes. It's called "cardboard" :P

Comment: related: [Carrying your circuits in a bag without bending/messing up parts?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/207419/7036)

Comment: cardboard and other paper conducts static so you dont want to use that for electronics.

Comment: When you buy assembled pcbs they will usuall be wrapped into anti static bags and packed into cardboard boxes with pink foam sometimes with individual slots. Unless your assembly is unusually esd sensitive or unusually large/heavy this should be enough electrical and mechanical protection

Answer (score 2):

Each board should be in its own static-shielding bag, preferably the metalized type (shiny gray color). After that, it doesn't matter as much what you use to protect them mechanically. Any sort of plastic or cardboard box will do, but preferably one that doesn't *generate* a lot of static.

Answer (score 0):

"Anti-static" bags are one thing. Dave Jones made some testing (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imdtXcnywb8). Really worth watching. In general the grey ones dissipate charge while the pink ones don't. In the case of foam cutouts - funny enough that I've seen those in both grey-black and pink versions (the grey ones being used in high-end electronics). They might be made of the same materials, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: The difference between the black foam and the pink foam is the same as the bags. The pink won't *generate* static, and the black will *dissipate* it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that loose components are more static sensitive than assembled boards.  This is because the power supply protects the circuit against static.

I use a component box with normal plastic trays lined with conductive foam.  This should be fine for hobby use.

c-: